# Reading file from directory with more than 10K files

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have a directory with multiple sub directories,each sub directory has more than `10K` xml files.

When there were 1000 files, it used to read random files in `5 secs`, whereas with increased file count it is taking more than `12 seconds`.

I am using below code for retriving file content:-

```
 if (File.Exists(xmlLogFilePath))
 {      
      string retrivedText = File.ReadAllText(xmlLogFilePath);     
 }
```

Can someone suggest of what can be done to improve performance.

.Net Version: 2.0

Comment: So where is the slowness? Writing the file or traversing the directories or checking if the file exists - or somewhere else? Have you timed it to see exactly where the time is going? And how many files are you writing in the 12 seconds?

Comment: @Matthew, reading file is taking time

Comment: You are unlikely to be able to speed it up then. How large is the file? It must be very large... is there any way you can make it smaller - perhaps by removing old lines every so often (assuming it's a log file)? Can you perhaps create a new file once per week by naming the file after the year and week number in some way?

Comment: Have you considered moving the data to a database, rather than storing that in files? Considering the large number of files.

Comment: If you dont have control on the file creation, consider using a SSD.

Comment: Idea: analyse the directory (not files!) fragmentation with contig (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897428.aspx).

Comment: As far as I remember the static methods of the file class do a lot of validation (like checking if the file exists, etc.). You could try using the instance methods which - as far as I know - could be a little bit faster...

Answer (score 2):

Here are few ways to consider:

1. Move the data to a database, considering the large amount of files.
2. If that is not possible, try to upgrade your HDD to an Solid State Drive.
3. Alternatively, you could split up the files onto separate Disks and read parallely.

Comment: I apologies should have been ReadAllText

Answer (score 2):

you can use Parallel Asynchronous I/O Method :

The following example demonstrates parallel processing by writing 10 text files.

```
public async void ProcessWriteMult()
{
    string folder = @"tempfolder\";
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    List<FileStream> sourceStreams = new List<FileStream>();

    try
    {
        for (int index = 1; index <= 10; index++)
        {
            string text = "In file " + index.ToString() + "\r\n";

            string fileName = "thefile" + index.ToString("00") + ".txt";
            string filePath = folder + fileName;

            byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

            FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
                FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
                bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);

            Task theTask = sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
            sourceStreams.Add(sourceStream);

            tasks.Add(theTask);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    finally
    {
        foreach (FileStream sourceStream in sourceStreams)
        {
            sourceStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose it is because the parallel processing described here belongs to .NET 4.0. The question deals about .NET 2.0. Anyway, this does not deserves a downvote IMHO.

Comment: Given that the speed limiting factor is most likely the IO, parallelizing it will not help significantly. In fact, it may be worse, due to task scheduling overhead. And this applies to writing as well as reading.

Comment: I think someone downvoted because the author edited his question and although your post was relevant to the original question now your post is less relevant. I upvoted you to get you back to even. Thank you for trying :) But Kris is right this probably isnt the best way to improve performance. There is overhead with the I/O and it makes more sense on a large number of large files. What the original poster wants is a better method/tool to read the files faster.

Answer (score 1):

The slowdown is caused by two different factors.

First, as there are more files, they will take more space in total. As you want to read a "random" file, the probability that it is in the disk cache will be lower. This will increase the average time to read the file, and there isn't much you can do about it, except maybe increasing the amount of RAM in your computer.

Secondly, a directory is a data structure that needs to be searched for the file. As a directory increases, i.e. as the number of files in a directory grows, this will take longer. This you can work with: make sure your directories are smaller. For example, create a directory for all files who's file name starts with a given character. This will speed up the searching.

Answer (score 0):

I think you lost time in searching for file record in the file system. And in the example above you're doing it twice: first on Exists() call, second on file opening in ReadAllText(). Probably, you can minimize file directory access using FileInfo structure. But I'd prefer to re-organize the files so one directory contains no more than 1000 files.

Answer (score 0):

According to the implementation of [File.ReadAllText(String path)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs#8a84c56a62fd8d45) it uses a StreamReader with a default buffer size of 1024 bytes (at least in .NET 4.5.1 - I'm not sure if it has changed). However you could maybe increase the performance for reading the files by using a higher buffer size resulting in less calls in the background.